# How do I use arguments in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay so I have this code, but when I try to use $announce, it doesn't write Hello back. In fact, it isn't responding to anything I put under the async def. How come?

I feel that I've done everything correctly, and the tutorials are for rewrite and up which I'm using.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import time
import random
import weather
from weather import Weather, Unit

prefix = '$'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix)
clattr = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
        await client.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game('have a nice day!'))
        print("Bot is now online!")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith("$hello"):
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(time())
  if message.content.startswith("$dm"): 
    user = client.get_user(393921960817721355)
    dm_channel = user.dm_channel
    if (dm_channel==None):
      dm_channel = await user.create_dm()
    await dm_channel.send(f"""Hello!""")
  if message.content.startswith("$servers"):
    await message.channel.send(clattr.guilds)
  if message.content.startswith("$help"):
    await message.channel.send(f"""This is the vanceBot. Made by vance and OYOHO#5964 (xray#4398 helped as well).\nThese are the current commands:\n$hello, which says "Hi" a few times \n$dm, which DMs a person\n$servers, which displays the number of servers that the bot is on\n$leave, to get the bot to leave\n$help, this command.\nThe prefix is $.""")
  if message.content.startswith("$pinghelp"):
    await message.channel.send(f"""||@everyone|| This is the vanceBot. Made by vance and OYOHO#5964 (xray#4398 helped as well).\nThese are the current commands:\n$hello, which says "Hi" a few times \n$dm, which DMs a person\n$servers, which displays the number of servers that the bot is on\n$leave, to get the bot to leave\n$help, this command.\nThe prefix is $.""")


@client.command()
async def announce(ctx, announcement):
  await ctx.send(f"""Hello""")




TOKEN = os.environ.get("DISCORD_BOT_SECRET")
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code as below, but be sure that discort.py is in the same folder with this code. If you get error please share the error/warning in your entry, it will help.

```
from discord import *
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import time
import random
import weather
from weather import Weather, Unit

prefix = '$'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix)
clattr = Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
        await client.change_presence(status = Status.online, activity = Game('have a nice day!'))
        print("Bot is now online!")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith("$hello"):
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(f"""Hi""")
    await message.channel.send(time())
  if message.content.startswith("$dm"): 
    user = client.get_user(393921960817721355)
    dm_channel = user.dm_channel
    if (dm_channel==None):
      dm_channel = await user.create_dm()
    await dm_channel.send(f"""Hello!""")
  if message.content.startswith("$servers"):
    await message.channel.send(clattr.guilds)
  if message.content.startswith("$help"):
    await message.channel.send(f"""This is the vanceBot. Made by vance and OYOHO#5964 (xray#4398 helped as well).\nThese are the current commands:\n$hello, which says "Hi" a few times \n$dm, which DMs a person\n$servers, which displays the number of servers that the bot is on\n$leave, to get the bot to leave\n$help, this command.\nThe prefix is $.""")
  if message.content.startswith("$pinghelp"):
    await message.channel.send(f"""||@everyone|| This is the vanceBot. Made by vance and OYOHO#5964 (xray#4398 helped as well).\nThese are the current commands:\n$hello, which says "Hi" a few times \n$dm, which DMs a person\n$servers, which displays the number of servers that the bot is on\n$leave, to get the bot to leave\n$help, this command.\nThe prefix is $.""")


@client.command()
async def announce(ctx, announcement):
  await ctx.send(f"""Hello""")




TOKEN = os.environ.get("DISCORD_BOT_SECRET")
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Okay I've tried it, it gives:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from discord import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

Yes I have installed discord.py.

Comment: What is your Python Version? Can you open Python IDE and run 
import discord
print discord.__version__
If discord installed properly it will show the version.

Comment: discord          1.0.1
discord.py       1.2.4
Python 3.7 64bit